# Programmatically Add multiple Products with Custom Options

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to develop a code in php which will take the order increment Id from an old order and will create a new order with same products along with the product custom options(if any).
Fetching par is fine even it was possible to add product via querystring but by that I can't add custom options. The cart page shows : Product Custom Options Required.

I think(not sure) I even succeeded in adding products with custom options via soap api but when I redirect to cart it shows an empty cart.

I'm a beginner, so please ignore any stupidity if it exists. :D
The code with the querystring is as below:

```
$form_key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
$arrProducts = array(
/*array
(
"product" => "3",
"qty" => 7
),*/
array
(
"product" => "1",
"qty" => 3,
"options" => array
                 (
                  2 => array(
                            "date" => "11/12/13",
                            "date_internal" => "2013-12-11 00:00:00"
                            ),
                  1 => "1"
                 )
header('Location: '.Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/form_key/'.$form_key.'/', $arrProduct));
```

So, this directs to a page with the product but asks me to chose the product options.
and when i use  the other product which is commented above, its a success.

Even i'm now able to add a product without custom(product with id='3') option in the cart. code is as follows:

```
<?php
require('../../../app/Mage.php'); //include mage.php
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$form_key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
//echo $form_key;
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

$product->load(2); 
//$product->setProductOptions();

$params = array(

            array

            (

            "product" => "3",

            "qty" => 1

            ),


            array
                (
                "product" => "2",

                "qty" => 2,

                "options" =>array
                                (
                                    2 => array
                                            (
                                                          "date" => "11/12/2013",
                                                    "date_internal"=> "2013-12-11 00:00:00"
                                                ),

                                    1 => "1"

                                    )
                    )
                );



  $cart->addProduct($product, $params);

  $cart->save(); 

   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

   header('Location:http://111.111.1.1/magento/checkout/cart');
    ?>
```

but it doesn't work for any product with custom options(product with id='2').
Error Message :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify the product required option(s).' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:594 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\pratmagento\panel\orders\try2addtocart.php(53): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 594

Comment: So you want to copy the last order (products+custom options) and increment the order id by one?

Comment: yes absolutely... i want that and couldn't set the value of custom option.

Comment: one of the custom option is date type. thanks in advance....

Comment: Could you tell us which the custom options (apart from data type) are so that we can help you, please?

Comment: type 1= date
type 2= dropdown (with 2 options only)

Comment: Is there any errors on the screen after you try to run this code?

Comment: yes!!!
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify the product required option(s).' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:594 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\pratmagento\panel\orders\try2addtocart.php(53): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 594

Comment: Please, have a look at function validateUserValue which is located at /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php and function validateUserValue which is located at /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Date.php    . It seems the error comes from there. I suggest editing your question to include the error PHP shows you. Let's wait until someone else have a look at this problem too.

Comment: yeah, i'm just going through it.
no solution yet. lets wait. thanks to you though.
done editing.

Answer (score 0):

It is required to set website_ids for the product.

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
```